# Save data from consecutive GET requests

Tags: javascript, django

I'm building a web application using django and javascript. I have a variable 'new_g' that I set by getting a value from the server, like so:

```
new_g = {{ new_g|safe }}
```

However I need to save this value on every page load so, for e.g.

```
new_g = {{ new_g|safe }}
var a = []
a.push(new_g)
```

So if after 3 GET requests, new_g has taken on the value 3,4,8 then a will be [3,4,8]. Is there any way to save data from all the GET requests from the server like this?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: {{ new_g|safe }} is this Angular? Please explain. Anyway, what you want to do is not possible because the variables are completely regenerated at each page refresh. One thing you can do is to use the Django session to store data and then read it in the frontend.

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? You just appear to be appending a value to an array, which yes you can do from a get request and yes you can do it (just not with the template tag)